# CKEditor - Custom image browser

Tags: php, javascript, plugins, ckeditor, file-browser

I'm currently developing a image browser in PHP and jQuery. I've managed to create a custom button plugin that opens my image browser in a new window (not a dialog box):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('imgbrowser',
{
    init: function(editor)
    {
        var pluginName = 'imgbrowser';
        editor.ui.addButton('Imgbrowser',
            {
                label: 'Image browser',
                command: pluginName,
                click: function (editor) { window.open('/publish/browser/index.php','Image Browser','width=900,height=600'); }
            });
    }
});
```

Is there anyone here who knows how to enable the callback function and how this will be used so that I can add the selected pictures into the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is the answer:

In the parent window I have this function:

```
function InsertHTML(file_path)
        {
            // Get the editor instance that we want to interact with.
            var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.page_content;
            var value = file_path;

            // Check the active editing mode.
            if ( oEditor.mode == 'wysiwyg' )
            {
                // Insert the desired HTML.
                oEditor.insertHtml( '<img src="' + value + '" />' );
            }
            else
                alert( 'You must be on WYSIWYG mode!' );
        }
```

page_content is the id of my textarea.

In the popup window I have this function:

```
function sendToParent(file_path) {
    window.opener.InsertHTML(file_path);
}


echo "<input type='button' value='Insert image' onclick='sendToParent(\"".$img_element."\")' />"
```